Is it feasible to track changes in the density of zero-point energy (ZPE) from the Big Bang to the present?
I'm exploring a hypothetical scenario where our observable universe exists as a bubble filled with zero-point energy (ZPE), surrounded by a larger ZPE-free space. Could this configuration potentially explain the universe's expansion? Imagine planets and stars as objects riding on expanding waves.
If we consider a situation where a ZPE-free vacuum is adjacent to a ZPE-full vacuum, would the energy between these regions tend to equalize, similar to how water finds its level? As this process disrupts the isotropy and uniformity of space, could it also influence the trajectories of cosmic bodies, making them move with the expanding wave?
Additionally, is it feasible to track changes in the density of ZPE from the Big Bang to the present, to determine if the overall energy density of the universe has been decreasing over time?

In your model, there would be two things: 1. a definite center of the Universe and 2. expansion speeds not proportional to distance from the observer. Neither of these things match with what we see. ZPE is also consequential of the way the quantum vacuum works, not some underlying fluid or field.
